# Multiple OR filtering with Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Here I filter the table by 1 column(keyId) and 1 value(keyId), and result type is Optional, it's correct.

```
override def findByKeyId(keyId: String): Future[Option[Event]] =
    db.run(events.filter(_.keyId === keyId).result.headOption)
```

Now I need filter by 1 column(keyId) and multiple values.

```
override def findByKeyIdBulk(keyIdSeq: Seq[Option[String]]): Future[Seq[Option[Event]]] = {

    db.run(
      events.filter { event =>
        keyIdSeq
          .map(_.map(keyId => event.keyId === keyId))
          .collect({ case Some(criteria) => criteria })
          .reduceLeftOption(_ || _)
          .getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
      }.result
    ) // Future[Seq[Event]]

  }
```

In this code expression of type `Future[Seq[Event]]` doesn't conform to 
`Future[Seq[Option[Event]]]`

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the point of having `Option[T]` as a return value. Returning `Seq[Option[T]]` is anti-pattern and here is why:

`Option[T]` makes total sense when there is no guarantee that you'll find anything. FindById is a great example where it is useful - we either find something and get `Some(value)` or we don't and get `None`.

But if you are planning to find by several ids and want a `Seq` of found values, then there are two cases: either `Seq` is empty and nothing was found or `Seq` contains some elements. There is no point in having `Option[T]` inside `Seq` because there won't be any `None`s inside the sequence. You'll be forced to use an extra pattern matching or extra map which is totally pointless.

I think you will be better off changing type signature to `Future[Seq[Event]]`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `events.result` will result in returning `Future[Seq[Event]]`. Using `filter` won't change that, so the resulting type is still `Future[Seq[Event]]`. In order to change it to `Future[Seq[Option[Event]]]` you'd have to lift values to `Option[Event]`:

```
db.run(
  events.filter { event =>
    keyIdSeq
      .map(_.map(keyId => event.keyId === keyId))
      .collect({ case Some(criteria) => criteria })
      .reduceLeftOption(_ || _)
      .getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
  }
  .map(_.map(Option(_))) //lifting Event to Option[Event]
  .result
) // Future[Seq[Option[Event]]]
```

Comment: Meanwhile you are corrent (lifting to Option is a literal solution) I think that it's pretty pointless and won't do any good. After all you will end up with a Seq of Some(value) (there won't be any None by design) and it will require an extra pattern matching or map which is not neccesary at all!